# COALESCE in DB2 returning empty

Tags: sql, db2

In DB2, I'm trying to get the first non-empty field of 3:

```
COALESCE(KONTAKT_MOB,KONTAKT_TLF,KUNDE_TLF_MOB)
```

Full SQL:

```
SELECT   KUNDE_PART_REF, KONTAKT_PART_REF, KUNDE_DIVISJON_KODE, 
         KUNDE_EMAIL_KUNDEKORT, KUNDE_TLF_MOB, KONTAKT_TLF, 
         KONTAKT_MOB, KUNDE_NAVN, KONTAKT_NAVN, KUNDE_PERS_ORG_KODE, coaleSce(KONTAKT_MOB,KONTAKT_TLF,KUNDE_TLF_MOB) as tlf
FROM     G00V.G79_KUNDE_KONTAKT_INFO_NL_CBT
where KUNDE_DIVISJON_KODE in ('L') and KUNDE_PERS_ORG_KODE not in ('O');
```

- KONTAKT_MOB is a varchar with length 15. It's never null, but it can
  be empty.
- KONTAKT_TLF is a varchar with length 50. It's never null,
  but it can be empty.
- KUNDE_TLF_MOB is a varchar with length 50. It's
  never null, but it can be empty.

When KONTAKT_MOB is empty, this works fine, the result is correct.
However, every time both KONTAKT_TLF and KUNDE_TLF_MOB are empty, the end result is also empty - even though KONTAKT_MOB contains 10 chars.

If I put COALESCE(KONTAKT_MOB,KONTAKT_TLF,KUNDE_TLF_MOB,'tomt'), then "tomt" is never used.
It's like it refuses to ever return KONTAKT_MOB.

Any ideas why?

Comment: COALESCE returns the first NOT-NULL value from the list, and is only useful if the database column allows NULL values. "Empty" is ambiguous, do you mean an empty string, spaces or such?  These are NOT NULL, so COALESCE will return them .  COALESCE treats spaces or empty string as NOT NULL. Fix your code (or your database , or your app) to either handle-empty strings or ensure they get stored as null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try something like this:

```
with data (KONTAKT_MOB,KONTAKT_TLF,KONTAKT_TLF_MOB) as (values
('','X',''),
('','','')
)
SELECT COALESCE(NULLIF(KONTAKT_MOB,''),
                NULLIF(KONTAKT_TLF,''),
                NULLIF(KONTAKT_TLF_MOB,''),
                'tomt')
from   data
```

Comment: The result is "tomt"

Comment: But now I got it working correctly, with your coalesce, thanks